# Input Remainder Prime Number

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that will tell the user if the inputted number is either a prime number or not. I would like to know how to format it to where it will return the remainder. I have the following .py file that I made, but I keep getting error "not all arguments converted during string formatting":

```
i = 2
x = input("Input your proposed prime number now:\n")
number = x % i
print (number)
```

Comment: try adding a `print(type(x))` before the modulus operation and you'll see that x is a string (use `int()` to cast to integer type)

Comment: Related [Python type Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092438/pythontypeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rishav had incorrect formatting, try:
`x = int(input(Input your proposed prime number now:\n"))`

if you are working with decimals, you can use:
`y = float(input("Input a decimal > "))`

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string in Python3. Use :

`x = int(input("Input your proposed prime number now:\n")`